# Are the empty string and some words of even length words of this language?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, sets

$L = \{w \in \{a,b\}^*\mid \text{the first, the middle, and the last characters of $w$ are identical}\}$.

I have my answers, but I need confirmation:

Is the empty string $\epsilon \in L$? Yes. Reason: there is no first, middle, or last character to break the rule.

A word of even length, assuming the first and last character of it are identical, again, must be in $L$, as there is no middle character in it to break the rule.

This is in the context of theory of computation.

Comment: And what about $\{w\in\{a,b\}^* \mid \text{the first character of } w \text{ is } a \}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since "the first, the middle, and the last characters of $w$ are identical" is not really well defined here (so there might be ambiguities like is $\epsilon\in L$?)

Probably it wont really matter for the question if you assume $\epsilon\in L$ or $\epsilon \notin L$ (other than some small change in the PDA or CFG) But if you really want to make sure everything is ok, then write (in the answer for the question) that there are ambiguities and this is how you interpeted them.

Comment: Let us forget about theory of computation. So, you are saying that the membership of $\epsilon$ in $L$ is ambiguous, right?

Comment: yes, since the sentence "the first, the second and the last characters of $w$ are identical" in ambiguous. if, say, it was defined as "$(|w|\in \mathbb N_{even} \wedge w_0 = w_n) \vee (|w| \in \mathbb N_{odd} \wedge w_0=w_n=w_{n/2})$"  Then membership would have been less ambigiuous, since it specifically stated about what "middle" means for even length words. (the case of $\epsilon$ still is undefined here)

Comment: The language L is not ambiguous. What is ambiguous is which language is meant by the description.